# cygwin / mintty color scheme woes

Tags: terminal, cygwin, colors, mintty

I heavily rely on Cygwin (that uses mintty) and SSH to work on remote systems on command lines and then using emacs in text mode as editor. I find the default color schemes of the cygwin shell horribly unreadable. Red on black is impossible to read, and the blue on black is even worse. I have tried the web based color scheme editor that gives the settings for .minttyrc file, and I wasn't able to produce anything more readable with so many trade-offs for various background - foreground color combinations.

My question: has anyone produced a really good readable color scheme that I could just use?

Comment: Mintty colors or Emacs colors ?

Comment: emacs is running in text mode on the terminal, so it all comes down to the same.

Comment: may be http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_playing_with_color_theme.html